# UK visa legal traineeship payment without a work visa?

Tags: uk-visa, russia

Under which condition and visa type can I conduct my own academic research sponsored by a non-UK HEI  and also be paid by a small UK-based company which does not have a sponsor certificate?

I am a Russian citizen doing a PhD in Italy. Within my PhD program, I am planning to have a research traineeship in the UK at a company which is not a certified sponsor, and offers a monthly payment. I am also waiting for the Erasmus scholarship results for Tier 4 visa.

Comment: You will have to get a Tier 2 visa, which means that they will have to have a sponsor license. But you do have some advantage here. PhD students have a special concession to be granted a Tier 2 visa (not subject to quota, not sure about RLMT but I think not as well). So as long as the program is recognized by the UK, and all of the other basic conditions are met, it should be no problem to obtain the visa quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately the sponsor is not certified.

Comment: You say unfortunate, but I wonder if they might not be able to do so quickly. It is a notably speedy process. I've all but seen it with my own eyes. I wish we could PM each other. It really depends on how much you really want to take part in this traineeship. There are ways to work within the rules to get it done.

Comment: What ways would be within the rules? I should update the information: I have an Erasmus+ traineeship grant for 12-months but my hosting organization is not a certified sponsor. Is it true that with Erasmus+ traineeship I can only apply for Tier 5 visa? Can I apply for Tier 4 with Erasmus+ traineeship grant for 12 months? I know that I can apply for other types if the period is not more than 6 months.